# What is the proper term for names typically assigned to people in countries using the first-middle-last format?

Tags: names

In countries where English is common, people typically have names in the format `<given name> <middle name> <family name>`.

- Is there a general term for this structure of name, as opposed to `<family name> <given name>`, which is sometimes used in Asia?
- If I meet someone from Canada, who has a name in the `<given name> <middle name> <family name>`-format, should I say they have a "Canadian name", and "English name", a "Western-style name", or should I use some other term?

Comment: You can say "they have a middle name" or "they don't have a middle name". Leaving this as a comment, since there could be a good term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_order#Name_order), the appropriate terms are *Eastern order* and *Western order*.  The wikipedia article says:

> Since a name is made up of several parts, the order in which those parts are arranged can be significant. The order *family-name given-name* is commonly known as the Eastern order and is used in Hungary, parts of Africa, and East Asia (for example in China, Japan, Korea, Malaysian Chinese, Singapore, Taiwan, Southern India, and Vietnam). The order *given-name family-name* is commonly known as the Western order and is usually used in most European countries and in countries that have cultures predominantly influenced by Western Europe (North and South America and Australia and New Zealand). ...

The article doesn't address what use (or not) of a middle name is called, except for brief discussion of *[Patronymics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patronymics)* and *[Matronymics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matronymics)* and saint's names as middle names.

Comment: That only is with respect to order, not with respect to 2-part and 3-part. It doesn't clarify if someone has a middle name.

Comment: Note, *[binominal](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/binominal)* clearly means "having two names", but *[trinominal](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/trinominal#English)* refers to trinomials instead of to having three names.